# I can't open 443 port

Tags: firewall, ssl, https, iis, windows-firewall

I'm trying to make public an https server with valid SSL. I can access my sites locally from the server's browser. So, it's ok. The page get loaded and SSL appear to be valid. But when I access from another computer I get ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.

I have already added port 443 in inbound rules in Windows firewall and i'm using IIS 10.

[image: Remote access]

[image: Server access]

Comment: If not on your system itself there is likely some firewall upstream in your connectivity which blocks access to your site. Contact your local IT department for help.

Comment: How to do this depends a great deal on your server's Internet connection, especially what firewalls (and/or NAT routers) are between it and the open Internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. Thanks for the comments. The solution was to contact my IT departament and request access to port 443.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).